# Qt 5 QComboBox setCurrentIndex

Tags: qt

I use :

> ui->Combobox->setCurrentIndex(1);

but this instruction doesn't call the function

> void on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1);

Why this behaviour ?

```
void ConsigneMouvement::show(int AxeType) 
{
    axeType = AxeType;
    switch(axeType)
    {
        case 1:
            ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(0);
            ui->comboBox->setEnabled(true);
        break;
        case 2 :
            ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(1);
            ui->comboBox->setEnabled(false);
        break;
        case 3 :
            ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(0);
            ui->comboBox->setEnabled(true);
        break;
        case 4 :
            ui->comboBox->setCurrentIndex(0);
            ui->comboBox->setEnabled(true);
        break;
    }
    this->exec();  
}
```

and the function

```
void ConsigneMouvement::on_comboBox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1) 
{
    if(arg1 == "Absolu")
        ui->label_distance->setText(tr("Position"));
    else
        ui->label_distance->setText(tr("Distance")); 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [simple, complete sample code](http://sscce.org) which shows the issue?

Comment: Does your index actually changes? The signal won't emit, if previous index was also 1.

Comment: Have you just posted your example code as an answer!? That is not acceptable, add it your question via the 'edit' button, and delete the 'answer'.

Comment: Where is your connect statement?

Answer (score 1):

setCurrentIndex() does not emit currentIndexChanged() signal if it is not really changed. It means that in your example the previous index was already 1.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the slot isn't connected automatically because you wrote *comboBox* in one place and *Combobox* in the other, so try:

```
void on_Combobox_currentIndexChanged(const QString &arg1);
```

//you'll need to run qmake before build

LE: i recommend to avoid the auto-connect feature and write the connect statements yourself (you need to be careful to avoid naming slots like on_WIDGETNAME_SIGNALNAME because you might end up with a slot called twice)